# how to make different marker by taking the Google MAPS ID API JAVASCRIPT III

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following table:
table KEPO
has the following files:
name_A
address_A
latitude_A
longitude_A
Jop_A
in the file type has the type SMALLINT which means 1 and 2
I want to make the display marker
if
Jop_A 1 = Marker 11.png
Jop_B 2 = marker 22.png
I use google maps fire javascript 3, I've been looking browsing2 but did not find a way in accordance with table I expected. please help.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sample is for google maps doc

> ```
>  function initMap() {
>    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
>    zoom: 4,
>    center: {lat: -33, lng: 151}
>  });
>
>  var image = 'images/beachflag.png';
>  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
>    position: {lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274},
>    map: map,
>    icon: image
>  });
> }
> ```

you can see this sample use th icon for the marker

you can simply change the file related to the image var depending the value you get from db
in your case

```
switch ( jop_A ) {
    case 1:
      image =  11.png;
      break;
   case  2: 
     image = 22.png;
} 

var yourMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {lat: latitude_A, lng: longitude_A},
  map: map,
  icon: image
});
```